# jQuery - Struggling to change background of whole webpage when hovering over one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to javascript and jQuery. I am trying to make it such that the background of my whole webpage (class = .background-image) changes when hovering over a specific element. I am unable to get it work. When I hover over the item (id = #ComingSoon), nothing seems to happen. There are currently no errors in the browser console. Can someone please tell me what could be wrong. I have been working at this for a couple of hours now making a series of minor changes with no success. I have searched for others with similar problems without success. Here are some extracts from my HTML and Javascript:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyvHi.png)
[JAVASCRIPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSAVI.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please check this. https://jsfiddle.net/ganesh16889/sz0k4xnL/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your issue is the `size(cover)` you have after your `url()`.

I just tried the code without it and it works fine:
(Working code)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
'use strict';
  $("#ComingSoon").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".background-image").css("background-image", "url(http://www.realpropertymanagementcolorado.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/denver-skyline.jpg)");
    $(".background-image").css("background-size", "cover");

    console.log("entered H2")
   })

   $("#ComingSoon").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".background-image").css("background", "none");

    console.log("Left H2")
  })

})
```

When I write it again with the `size(cover)` you have, it breaks:
(broken code)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
'use strict';
  $("#ComingSoon").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".background-image").css("background-image", "url(http://www.realpropertymanagementcolorado.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/denver-skyline.jpg) size(cover)");
    $(".background-image").css("background-size", "cover");

    console.log("entered H2")
   })

   $("#ComingSoon").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".background-image").css("background", "none");

    console.log("Left H2")
  })

})
```

Comment: My pleasure! If it helped, can you please mark the answer as the correct solution to your problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if u r using jquery try it..

```
$(function(){
    $('#comingSoon').hover(function(){
        /*do something when moseover*/
    },
    function(){
        /*do something when mouse-left*/
    });
});
```

Comment: I will try to implement this. Thank you for the suggestion.